# Part of proof of solutions to linear diophantine equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading a proof for the integer solutions to $ax + by = c$ (the coefficents are integers).

It states that there are $w_0$ and $z_0$ such that $aw_0 + bz_0 = d$, where $d = \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$.
Then let $x_0 = w_0k$ and $y_0 = z_0k$. And if $x'$, $y'$ is a solution of $ax + by = c$, then $ax' + by' = ax_0 + by_0$.

In the next step both sides are divided by $d$. I understand how that leads to the result, but it seems arbitrary to me to divide by $d$. If we were to multiply both sides by $d$, for instance, we would still have equivalent equations yet we would obtain a different solution set for the original equation. So how is it necessary to divide by d?

Comment: Note that a solution only exists when $\gcd(a,b)|c$. In this case, dividing by $\gcd(a,b)$ we get an equivalent equation with coprime coefficients. Hence, WLOG we can assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: I don't see how this is always true. For example, with 5x + 10y = 15, gcd(5,10)|15 yet 5 and 10 are not coprime.

Comment: What I mean is that we can transform the equation into an equivalent equation with coprime coefficients, in your case $x+2y=3$. So it is sufficient to discuss this case.